# Items in value of $100?

Tags: phrase-usage

I'm developing a webshop that provides free shipping when the cart total is above a certain amount, let's say $100. In case a customer has a cart with $30 subtotal, she/he has to add items in value of $70 for free shipping.

So I want to display the following information as succinct as possible: *Add more items to your cart in value of $70 for free shipping.*

Being a non-native speaker I'm uncertain about this part: **"items in value of ..."**.

Is that correct? (Any other improvements are welcome)

Comment: Add $70 worth of purchases for free shipping. $70 more in purchases gets you free shipping.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Spend $70 more to qualify for free shipping.